# updating tableview and coredata

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have some data in my Core Data and I am showing it on tableview. I want to update tableview row when I am clicking on the cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ItemTableViewCell

            cell.starImage.image = UIImage(named: "Gray star icon")

            cell.selectionStyle = .none

            let context = coreData.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Item")

            do {
                let result = try context.fetch(request)
                let img = UIImage(named: "Gray star icon")
                for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {

                    let data = img!.pngData() as NSData?

                    data?.setValue(data, forKey: "starImage")
                 }

            } catch {
                print("Failed")
            }

            coreData.saveContext()
            tableView.reloadData()
        }



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? ItemTableViewCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    cell.itemName.text = itemCategoryNameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.itemDescription.text = itemDescriptionArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.itemCategory.text = itemCategoryTypeArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.starImage.image = UIImage(data: itemStarArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(data: itemImageArray[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

But I am getting some error like :-

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:  this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key starImage.'

Comment: Can you add an exception breakpoint and find the line of code causing the crash? Did you definitely add a UIImageView called `starImage` to the ItemTableViewCell?

Comment: data?.setValue(data, forKey: "starImage") .         This line causing crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consolidate your variable names: There are two different `data` variables in the loop which causes confusion and the error

Better

```
for item in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
   let data = img!.pngData() as? NSData
   item.setValue(data, forKey: "starImage")
}
```

Nevertheless I recommend to use more specific types and create the image only once

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")

do {
    let result = try context.fetch(request)
    let img = UIImage(named: "Gray star icon")
    let data = img!.pngData() as? NSData
    for item in result {
       item.starImage = data
    }
} catch {
    print("Failed", error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now there is no crash . But after doing this i am getting all the image as "Gray star icon"  But i want to update only the perticular cell, what i am selecting

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how the `Item` entity is related to the data source. I just answered the question to fix the error.

Comment: actually i want to change the image of the particular cell by selecting it. but when i am selecting any of the tableview cell, it changes all the cell image . how to make change only on the particular selecting tableview cell.how to get particular cell's index path so that it will update this cell only

Comment: I understand what you want. Once again, ***how is the `Item` entity related to the data source***?

Comment: Actually I am unable to understand . I have one entity “Item”.  It have attribute starImage which is type binary data. I am saving it to database like.  - if let img = UIImage(named: "star") {
                let data = img.pngData() as NSData?
                item.starImage = data as! Data
            }

Comment: Please edit your question and add the `cellForRowAt` method. If `Item` represents the data source you don't need to fetch any data.

Comment: i have added cellForRowAtIndexpath Method in question

Comment: Unfortunately this does not enlighten how `Item` is related to the data source, so I can't answer the question how to update only one image. And you are strongly discouraged from using multiple arrays as data source. Don't do that, that's horrible. Why don't you use the entity directly?

Comment: Actually i am started programming with swift recently . so i don't have much idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time by answering my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this. here I have just fatched all records from core data once at a time and then after selection of Tableview cell that particular selected data will be updated and saved into core data and the cell image will also gate updated.

```
// GET DATA FROM CORE DATA...
func fetchData() {
        let context = coreData.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Item")

            do {
                let result = try context.fetch(request)
                managedObjects = result as! [NSManagedObject] //managedObjects             is a global array for the table content
                tableView!.reloadData()

            } catch {
                print("Failed")
            }

   }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ItemTableViewCell

            cell.starImage.image = UIImage(named: "Gray star icon")

            cell.selectionStyle = .none

            self.editData(with: self.managedObjects[indexPath.row], indexPath: indexPath)

    }

 func editData(with object: NSManagedObject, indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let img = UIImage(named: "Gray star icon")
        let data = img!.pngData() as NSData?
        (object as! Item).starImage = data
        coreData.saveContext()
        managedObjects[indexPath.row] = object
    }
```